# How to display preview thumbnail while scrubbing the video.

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, preview, data-scrubbing

I am trying to display the preview thumbnail when user move his finger over video scrubber.

The only solution I m finding is to extract thumbnails using some 3rd party tool and save it to server or pass it to app via some JSON.

What I m trying to do is something similar to JwPlayer (http://jwplayer.electroteque.org/controls-preview)

Any idea where to start?

Or is here any standard protocol that support manual generated thumbnails? Or i need to go with my own feed format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know what the configuration of your project is, but one possibility is too actually instantiate a mini player and display the progress of the video as the user the slides. So essentially this "mini player" would appear when the user begins drag, and skip to whatever time is specified, and pause. It is similar to a project I am working on now. This is a great reference as well: http://www.autodeskresearch.com/pdf/p1159-matejka.pdf. This technique is much different then the one I suggested, but is another alternative depending on your scenario.

Comment: in your case, whole video need to be loaded in advance...  I wanted to do it for online streaming

Answer (score 0):

This is now standard in players that support preview thumbnails (for scrubbing) in VTT files.

A great player that does this is plyr (plyr.io).

See instructions here: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#preview-thumbnails

If you want to generate them automatically, there's an NPM for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprite-vtt-generator

Comment: it was a pretty old question. I will explore more about this project in new future.

Does it not require for the whole video to download? or can I pass an array of manually generated thumbnails?

the idea is, if user suddenly scrub to 75%.. i don't need to wait for my video to download, the images might take a little time to download, that's ok.

Comment: Yep! No need to even download any of the video. The VTT file includes closed captioning and optionally, scrub thumbnails. The scrub thumbnails are just sprite sheets with like 100 small thumbnails all in the same image (configurable), so if someone suddenly scrubs to 75% of a 2 hour movie, all the browser would be doing is downloading a single image.  You could configure it so that, for speed reasons, you wanted to download a single image with 100 thumbnails, and each thumbnail representing 1% of the video, This means the initial ~100kb image is all that would be needed/no downloads at all.